# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4-runtime (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4)
     Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.PivotPoint found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4-runtime (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4)
     Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.ScalableType found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4-runtime (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4)
     Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.ScalableVideoView found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4-runtime (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4)
     Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.ScaleManager found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4-runtime (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4)    
     Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.ScaleManager$1 found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4-runtime (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4)  
     Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.Size found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4-runtime (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4)
```

I can't solve this problem, any suggestions? I also examined the issues, but I couldn't get any results from what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue in
`android => build.gradle` file in `react-native-video-processing` package.

instead of

```
implementation 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4'
```

I was able to solve it by putting

```
implementation 'com.github.adityaxjha:AndroidScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b'
```

Because it was actually forced to call the same packages with different versions.